# Autocorrelation function of a random walk process

Tags: econometrics, statistics, stochastic-processes

What is the intuition behind the result that the autocorrelation function of a random walk process $y_{t}=y_{t-1}+e_{t}$ tends to 1 as $t\rightarrow 0$? Thank you.

Comment: Tends to 1? Can you provide source for that statement? It should be 0 for the process you describe

Comment: This isn't true - by inspection, the correlation between successive random walk outputs (for any $t$) should be very high, differing from 1 only to the extent that $var[e_t]$ is large.  With that said, I don't think the problem is being posed correctly.

Comment: @1muflon1 Given the random walk process $y_{t}=y_{t-1}+e_{t}$, the auto correlation function is given by $corr(y_{t}, y_{t-h})=(\frac{t-h}{t})^{1/2}=(1-\frac{h}{t})^{1/2}$, which tends to 0 as t tends to infinity. What is the intuition behind this result?

Comment: @heh You are gravely mistaken, and I refer you to my proof to this effect commented above.

Comment: @BobCharles So in the question you say $t \to \infty$ but in the comment you say it's $t \to 0$?

Comment: @Art no, you are mistaken. As a general rule, please read carefully the original post before making remarks of this nature. (this ought to be obvious).

Comment: @Art Given you have yet to express but an iota of penitence regarding the mistake you have made—let alone demonstrated a will to, in the future, conduct yourself otherwise—I have no option but to report you.

Comment: @BobCharles If you look at the "edit" history you could see very clearly that you edited from $t \to \infty$ to $t \to 0$ at 14:55. And you said I'm "mistaken" at 14:56. Not very nice.

Answer (score 1):

By recursive substitution you obtain $y_t = \sum_{j=0}^t e_{t-j}.$ Thus $\forall p \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{.2cm} y_{t-p} = \sum_{j=0}^{t-p} e_{t-p-j}.$

Under the usual white noise assumption for the errors $i \neq j \Rightarrow E(e_je_i) =0\Rightarrow Cov(y_t, y_{t-p}) = E(\sum_{j=0}^{t-p} e_{t-p-j}^2) = (t-p+1)\sigma_e^2.$

$Var(y_t) = E(\sum_{j=0}^{t} e_{t}^2) = (t+1)\sigma_e^2 \hspace{.2cm} \wedge Var(y_{t-p}) = E(\sum_{j=0}^{t-p} e_{t-p-j}^2)(t-p+1)\sigma_e^2.$

$\Rightarrow \rho_t(p) = \frac{(t-p+1)\sigma_e^2}{\sqrt{(t+1)\sigma_e^2}\sqrt{(t-p+1)\sigma_e^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{(t-p+1)}}{\sqrt{(t+1)}}.$

$\Rightarrow lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \rho_t(p) = 1 \hspace{.2cm} \wedge \Rightarrow lim_{p\rightarrow t} \rho_t(p) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(t+1)}}$.

$\Rightarrow$ for fixed $p$ $lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \rho_t(p) = lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{(t-p+1)}}{\sqrt{(t+1)}}= 1$

Comment: Thank you, what is the intuition behind this result?

Comment: @BobCharles $y_{t-p}$ is entirely contained in $y_{t}$. The larger $t$ is the smaller is the relative contribution of the p values that are in   $y_{t}$ but not in $y_{t-p}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good discussion on random walks: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-random-walk-times-series-forecasting-python/

Hopefully after reading it, you'll be able to see how your question is probably not well-posed, and correct it so that we can help you.  For example, the autocorrelation function is *not* run over $t$, it's run over $k$ where $k$ indexes the lag order - in that case, as @1muflon1 notes, running $k \rightarrow \infty$ should see the correlation fall to zero.

Comment: But, given the random walk process $y_{t}=y_{t-1}+e_{t}$, the auto correlation function is given by $corr(y_{t}, y_{t-h})=(\frac{t-h}{t})^{1/2}=(1-\frac{h}{t})^{1/2}$, which tends to 0 as t tends to infinity. What is the intuition behind this result?

Comment: @BobCharles You are gravely mistaken. The expression tends to 1 as $t \to \infty$, as shown in your other post: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/34102/limit-of-random-walk-auto-correlation-function